# Scheduling weekly in MS Project

Tags: microsoft-project, project-management, microsoft-project-2010

MS Project tracks allocation of resources "daily". In other words MSP shows over-allocation or under-allocation of a resource on "per day" basis.

If you load a resource with 12h work on a 8h day then Resource Usage view shows it red. When you set the timescale of "Resource Usage" view to weeks, it still paints the week red even if only one day of the week is over-allocated and the rest of the week is completely empty.

I want to do task planning on a weekly basis and let everybody do their own planing for the week in their heads. As long as the workload on a resource for a week is not greater that 5d, there is no over-allocation for me and so that week is not be painted red.

Can this be done in MS Project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. On MS-Project 2010 go to Levelling Options on the resource tab.
Change the field "Look for Overrallocation on a" from Day-to-Day basis to Week-to-Week basis.

The same option is there on prior versions of MS-P IIRC, but you might need to look around for them- It has been a while since I used a prior version.

Comment: This is what I was searching for ... perfect

Comment: I did try to follow your suggestion, but even by selecting "Week-to-week" basis in the Levelling Options dialog, I still get the work hours shown in red if a resource is loaded with more than 8h a day even though the week total does not exceed 40h: